# Reading Data with Groups of Columns using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel sheet like this:

[image]

Roughly this as CSV:

```
,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,
,baseline,,,,scenario1,,
Year,A value,Another value,Etc.,Year,A value,Another value,Etc.
1900,4.74,7.08,0.00,1900,4.74,7.08,293.72
...
```

In reality there are more columns but they always have the same names. There are also a multiple but unknown number of scenarios, all with the same column names. I'm trying to read this in Pandas. Right now I don't need to do any calculations (though this may change). I mostly just want a nice way to navigate it.

So I've taken out the duplicate `Year` columns as they will always be the same, and set the `Year` as the index, which all works well, but for now I'm skipping the first header (with `baseline`, `scenario1`, etc.). I want some way of dealing with each year but being able to grab the value for each scenario out, for example "I want the value the `Another value` column for all scenarios for the `Year` `2013`.

Later I might want to get averages (e.g. average `Another value` across all scenarios) or do other similar calculations.

So far I have:

```py
df = pd.read_excel(
    "sample_data.xlsx",
    index_col=0,
    skiprows=3,
    usecols=lambda x: not x.startswith("Year."),
)
```

Which gives me this:

```
        A value  Another value      Etc.  A value.1  Another value.1      Etc..1
Year                                                                            
1900   4.738148       7.079923  0.000000   4.738148         7.079923  293.723450
1901   4.813111       7.179976  0.000000   4.813111         7.179976  294.029846
1902   4.881362       7.281056  0.000000   4.881362         7.281056  294.335663
1903   5.073858       7.503372  0.000000   5.073858         7.503372  294.586121
1904   5.104264       7.569910  0.000000   5.104264         7.569910  294.732697
...         ...            ...       ...        ...              ...         ...
2096  82.631828     109.509178  1.743965 -31.377947       -20.046871  337.782776
2097  82.983414     109.944275  1.749330 -31.621614       -20.278734  335.790863
2098  83.330070     110.372986  1.754694 -31.862324       -20.508474  333.807678
2099  83.671852     110.795380  1.760058 -32.102043       -20.738163  331.832764
2100  84.008766     111.211464  1.765422 -32.339836       -20.966856  329.865570
```

This is tolerable but I'd really like to have them "grouped" somehow by the scenario name (baseline, scenario1, any any others). I suppose what I'd like to be able to do is something like `df["2020"]["A value"]` or the other way around, but I'm not sure how to do this, or if it's even the right approach. I feel like this would require a MultiIndex, but I'm not sure how to set that up with this data.

Here is the real structure, without data, saved to CSV:

```
,baseline,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,scenario1,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Time,"Global CO2 emissions
(GtonsCO2/year)","Global CO2 Equivalent Emissions
(GtonsCO2/year)","Atm conc CO2
(ppm)","Equivalent CO2
(ppm)","Temperature change from preindustrial
(Degrees C)",Sea Level Rise from 2000 (mm),"Global cumulative CO2
(GtonsCO2)","Global cumulative C
(GtonsC)","Budget of C remaining
(GtonsC)","Global CH4 anthro emissions
(Mtons/year)","Global N2O Anthro Emissions
(Mtons/year)","Global SF6 emissions
(tons/year)","Global PFC emissions
(tons/year)","Global CO2eq emissions from HFC
(GtonsCO2e/year)",Time,"Global CO2 Emissions
(GtonsCO2/year)","Global CO2 Equivalent Emissions
(GtonsCO2/year)","Atm conc CO2
(ppm)","Equivalent CO2
(ppm)","Temperature change from preindustrial
(Degrees C)",Sea Level Rise from 2000 (mm),"Global cumulative CO2
(GtonsCO2)","Global cumulative C
(GtonsC)","Budget of C remaining
(GtonsC)","Global CH4 anthro emissions
(Mtons/year)","Global N2O Anthro Emissions
(Mtons/year)","Global SF6 emissions
(tons/year)","Global PFC emissions
(tons/year)","Global CO2eq emissions from HFC
(GtonsCO2e/year)"
1900,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1900,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1901,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1901,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1902,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1902,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1903,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1903,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
1904,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,1904,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

There are annoyingly newlines in the headers, but they do seem to get picked up correctly in Pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, but a little tricky as a result of the non-rectangularity of your data. Pandas allows data to be read with multiple levels of columns, but your issue is that your first level of header has cells missing (i.e. 'baseline' does not appear in cell C3.) Pandas will fill these missing cells with an 'Unnamed' column, but won't recognize that these unnamed columns should be 'baseline'.

In order to mitigate this, we'll have to rename the columns levels. Then we'll set the index to be year, and drop this column from all the scenarios:

First, we read the file without setting the index, and without skipping columns:

```
df = pd.read_excel("sample_data.xlsx", header=[2, 3])

  Unnamed: 0_level_0 baseline Unnamed: 2_level_0 Unnamed: 3_level_0 Unnamed: 4_level_0 scenario1 Unnamed: 6_level_0 Unnamed: 7_level_0
                Year  A value      Another value               Etc.               Year   A value      Another value               Etc.
0               1900     4.74               7.08                0.0               1900      4.74               7.08             293.72
```

Then, we build lists of the two levels of the columns so that we can assign them later:

```
scenarios = [col for col in df.columns.get_level_values(0) if not col.startswith('Unnamed')]
values = []
for col in df.columns.get_level_values(1):
    if col not in values:
        values.append(col)
```

This gives us multiindex column levels of:

```
scenarios
['baseline', 'scenario1']
```

```
values                                                                                                                                                                                              

['Year', 'A value', 'Another value', 'Etc.']
```

Now we assign the new multiindex columns using these level lists:

```
df.columns = df.columns.from_product([scenarios, values], names=['scenario','value'])

scenario baseline                            scenario1                              
value        Year A value Another value Etc.      Year A value Another value    Etc.
0            1900    4.74          7.08  0.0      1900    4.74          7.08  293.72
```

Finally, we assign the baseline year as the index and drop year from all the scenarios:

```
df = df.set_index(('baseline', 'Year'), drop=False)
df = df.drop('Year', axis=1, level=1)

scenario         baseline                    scenario1                      
value             A value Another value Etc.   A value Another value    Etc.
(baseline, Year)                                                            
1900                 4.74          7.08  0.0      4.74          7.08  293.72
```

One final note: as a general rule, keep your data rectangular! If you do that, automated processing will be a lot easier.

**EDIT:** The issue you're having is that you have two columns which are supposed to be the same, but are spelled slightly differently:

Column 1:

```
Global CO2 emissions
(GtonsCO2/year)
```

Column 16:

```
Global CO2 Emissions
(GtonsCO2/year)
```

To handle cases like this, you'll want to select the second level of the columns in a different way:

```
df = pd.read_excel("sample_data.xlsx", header=[0, 1])

scenarios = [col for col in df.columns.get_level_values(0) if not col.startswith('Unnamed')]

# Instead of taking one of each unique column names, we take the first n columns,
# where n is the total number of columns divided by the number of scenarios
values = df.columns.get_level_values(1)[:int(len(df.columns) / len(scenarios))]

df.columns = df.columns.from_product([scenarios, values], names=['scenario','value'])
df = df.set_index(('baseline', 'Time'), drop=False)
df = df.drop('Time', axis=1, level=1)

scenario                                      baseline                                                   ...                         scenario1                                                  
value            Global CO2 emissions\n(GtonsCO2/year) Global CO2 Equivalent Emissions\n(GtonsCO2/year)  ... Global PFC emissions\n(tons/year) Global CO2eq emissions from HFC\n(GtonsCO2e/year)
(baseline, Time)                                                                                         ...                                                                                    
1900                                               NaN                                              NaN  ...                               NaN                                               NaN
1901                                               NaN                                              NaN  ...                               NaN                                               NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As the data comes from an external source, it's not possible to get it in a better format, unless we pre-process it first. Can you explain a bit what you mean about rectangularity? What makes this dataset non-rectangular, and how could it be made to be so? A link explaining the concept would be fine.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a wiki page, but I got a hit on an [OReilly book](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/practical-statistics-for/9781491952955/ch01.html#RectangularData). Rectangular data will have a meaningful value at every row-column permutation. This could be a datum, a label, or even a missing value, but the row-column address has meaning in the dataset. Your data is non-rectangular because, for example, cell A3 doesn't have a value. The organization of the dataset implies that cell A3 will be the Scenario for the Year in column A, however, the cell is blank!

Comment: I seem to have a problem with the `df.columns.from_product(...)` line. I get an error such as `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 8 elements, new values have 28 elements`.

Comment: The length of the scenarios list times the length of the values list must equal the number of columns (i.e. every scenario must have all values.) This is the "product" in `from_product`. This why all Year columns must be read and cannot be set as index in the read.

Comment: I think the issue is my `scenarios` is different from your output. I get: `['baseline', 'baseline', 'baseline', 'baseline', 'scenario1', 'scenario1', 'scenario1']`. If I remove the duplicates this fixes it for the test data, but when using the real data (the same but way more columns) it no longer works. I'm not sure exactly how to solve it, or what it's trying to do.

Comment: Each label in the level lists must be unique. If you run the code in my example, scenarios should not have duplicates, because your image of your XLS does not have duplicates (i.e. "baseline" appears only once, in cell B3) The function [`from_product`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) creates a multiindex from the product of the labels of the level lists you pass it. In our case, scenarios and values. It creates one column for each scenario-value pair. This only works if your dataset has that number of columns. How many does it?

Comment: It's strange, I'm using the same data and code, but I get the duplicates. I've checked for any hidden values in the sheet, and the dataframe looks correct, just one column each of 'baseline' and 'scenario1', but still I get the duplicates in the list.

Comment: That can be fixed by using the same loop used to make the values list, but the important thing is that you have the right number of columns. How many scenarios do you have? How many total columns?

Comment: Switching to a loop to remove duplicates fixes it for the test data but oddly not the real data. The test data is as you see it. The "real" data is not complete as it's missing scenarios, but it has 2 scenarios (just baseline and scenario1) with 14 columns each, not including the Year. However, the Year is repeated as in the test data here, which I think might be messing with it (but if it is this, why doesn't it break with the test data?).

Comment: The year should be repeated. Your "real" data must have 28 columns (2 scenarios * 14 values). How many total columns are there? Try exporting your XLS to a CSV and looking at it manually.

Comment: It seems right to me. Including the Year columns, there are 30.

Comment: If the test data works, but the real data doesn't, then the test data isn't representative of the real data. Post the first ~10 lines of the real data.

Comment: I've added the real structure. Data is removed though, it's not mine to give out.

Comment: Your issue was two slightly different columns that were supposed to be the same. See my edit. Non-rectangularity strikes again!

Comment: Blargh, I didn't catch that and was looking for exactly something like it. This does raise a similar error for me but it seems to work when I make sure the scenarios list is unique, so I can finally accept this, thanks for all the effort.

Comment: Happy to help. If I've convinced you about the importance of rectangularity, it was all worth it.